# Regarding dom4j,iCal4j and backport-util-concurrent Export Control Classification Number (ECCN)

Tags: dom4j, ical4j

We would like know below mentioned details to use dom4j,iCal4j and backport-util-concurrent in commercial product

Can anyone tell me if the Java code contains encryption - or even better
can anyone tell me what will be export code (ECCN) for dom4j,iCal4j and backport-util-concurrent?

can anyone tell me what export code (ECCN) to use when distributing product with dom4j,iCal4j and backport-util-concurrent?

more info on ECCN Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_Control_Classification_Number

With Regards,
Kasim Basha Shaik

Answer (score -1):

iCal4j ECCN is **n/a**(not applicable).since,ical4j is not developed in the US so I don't believe it is subject to export restrictions. Either way there is not really any encryption code in ical4j, with the only encoding being BASE64 encoding of binary values.

(above information is provided by the "**Ben**" creator of iCal4j URL [here](http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Main_Page%22) )

In both dom4j source from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dom4j/files/dom4j-2.0.0-ALPHA-2/dom4j-2.0.0-ALPHA-2-sources.jar/download%22) and 
backport-util-concurrent source from  [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/backport-jsr166/files/backport-jsr166/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-Java50-3.1.zip/download%22)

I scanned through the code for the following key words.
- AlgorithmParameters
- CertificateFactory
- CertPathBuilder
- CertPathValidator
- CertStore
- Cipher
- AES
- DES
- DESede
- RSA
- KeyFactory 
- KeyGenerator
- Hmac
- KeyPairGenerator
- KeyStore
- Mac
- MessageDigest
- SecretKeyFactory
- Signature
- TransformService
- XMLSignatureFactory

Encryption related code not found and above encryption key word are taken from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher%22)

form the above code scan,I came a conclusion that ECCN for dom4j and backport-util-concurrent is  **n/a**